# Does the Corsair Hydro H55 fit LGA775?

Tags: water-cooling, lga775

I have a LGA775 motherboard (ASUS P5GC) and I wonder if I can fit the Corsair Hydro H55 on it?

Comment: A better place to post this would be at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Question re-created there: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10246/10315

Comment: @K7AAY the question was deleted from hardwarerecs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it kind of fits.

You'll have to remove the screw fittings from the bracket you put behind the motherboard and then just mount it as you would, without the large bracket itself.

The pump will sit very tightly on the CPU.

To remove the fittings from the bracket I used a lighter to soften the plastic just enough so that I could remove the fitting (like 10 seconds, 3 cm away).

Now my Intel Duo is 27 degrees celsius and makes no sound.